# How to keep line breaks when email gets text?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using phpmailer to do send email function, now my problem is when I pass the textarea value post to the phpmailer function, it cannot keep line breaks to send the email to the selected recipient.

For example, if I want to send content from textarea which is:

```html
A lion was once sleeping in the jungle when a mouse started running up and down his body just for fun. 
This disturbed the lion’s sleep, and he woke up quite angry.
```

Below is my sample code:

```php
$tajuk_email = $_POST['tajuk_email'];
$content= $_POST['content'];
$content_1 = "<p style='white-space: pre-wrap;'>".$content."</p>";
$checkbox_value = $_POST['checkbox_value'];
$checkbox_value = str_replace("=>", ":", $checkbox_value); 
$recipients = json_decode( "{" . $checkbox_value . "}", true);
require 'plugins/mail/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();                                //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';     //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Port = 465;                              //Sets the default SMTP server port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
$mail->Username = 'st9overfindsolution@gmail.com';                  //Sets SMTP username
$mail->Password = '88853sdhdfh';                    //Sets SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                      //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
$mail->From = "Tester";                 //Sets the From email address for the message
$mail->FromName = "Tester 1";               //Sets the From name of the message
foreach ($recipients  as $email => $name) {
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name); 
} 
$mail->AddCC("aaa@gmail.com", "sagsa"); //Adds a "Cc" address
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                           //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                            //Sets message type to HTML             
$mail->Subject = $tajuk_email;              //Sets the Subject of the message
$mail->Body = $content_1;               //An HTML or plain text message body
```

The result for content is, it cannot keep line break to send an email:

```
A lion was once sleeping in the jungle when a mouse started running up and down his body just for fun. This disturbed the lion’s sleep, and he woke up quite angry.
```

[image: result]

What I have tried?

1. I have used `white-space:pre-wrap:` to keep the line break, but cannot work.
2. I have used `$content= nl2br($_POST['content']);`, but cannot work.
3. I have used `$content = trim($_POST['content']); $content = nl2br($content );`, but cannot work.
4. I don't have tried the `CKEditor function`, because I want to keep using textarea function to send the content.

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Since you have `$mail->IsHTML(true);`, you need to convert the line breaks to HTML line breaks: `<br />` using nl2br(). You say that you've tried that, but that should work. Have you tried sending it as text? Also, have you checked the email in different mail clients, so it isn't the mail client you're using that does something strange?

Comment: `nl2br()` worked for me. At least in mails sent with `phpmailer/phpmailer` package. I've hoped to solve the same problem for Microsoft Word documents made with `vench/vsword` package, but sadly it didn't work there.